# Delete files from any existing folders or subfolders in google drive and keep the last updated one only using App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have to keep the last modified files(any files) and remove(move to trash) other files having similar name from  any folder or subfolder within google drive using app script only. How can I do it? please share code if possible. Thanks!

Comment: Try using recursion and DriveApp

Comment: This video might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GMf30xyRv9M

Comment: Do you mean excel files or google sheets files?

Answer (score 0):

Delete All Sheets from All subfolders

```
function keepLastUpdated() {
  const fldr = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.toast('Entry');
  findLastUpdated(fldr);
  ss.toast('EOF');
}

//var level = 1;
function findLastUpdated(folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder()) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let fs = [];
  const files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGlE_SHEETS);// or MICROSOFT_EXCEL you choose
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    let file = files.next();
    fs.push(file)
  }
  fs.sort((a,b) => {
    return new Date(b.getLastUpdated()).valueOf() - new Date(a.getLastUpdated()).valueOf();
  });
  fs.shift();
  fs.forEach(f => Drive.Files.remove(f.getId()));
  const subfolders = folder.getFolders()
  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
    let subfolder = subfolders.next();
    //level++;
    findLastUpdated(subfolder);
  }
  //level--;
}
```

This could take a while.  It takes me about six to eight minutes to build a tree file structure of my drive in a spreadsheet and I only have about 3.06 GB used in my drive.  I use the levels for keeping track of my recursion depth.  I believe it can go to a max of 1000

Comment: Will this delete all old spreadsheets and keep the latest modified one from  within all folders and subfolders  in google drive?

Comment: I recommend testing it first on test files

Comment: Okay bro. I will let you know after testing. actually I have to delete all similar naming spreadsheets(lets say we have 5 spreadsheets of name test.xlsx, i have to delete the old 4 and keep the last updated one.

Comment: HII @Cooper, it is showing this error when i am saving it as my project. "Syntax error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list line: 18 file: driveAutomate1.gs"

Comment: i fixed above error.another error is  showing like "cant read property toast of null".

Comment: when i  commented the toast part ,again one error thown- "Exception: Argument cannot be null: mimeType
findLastUpdated @ driveAutomate1.gs:13
keepLastUpdated @ driveAutomate1.gs:5..  help out

Comment: error also showing in line18.a an b are not defined

Comment: Can anyone give  a strong solution to that?

Comment: Do you have a copy of the current code with all of your edits and please provide a complete error message.  I had no intention of running such a script on my account so as far as I'm concerned debugging it is your problem but I'm happy to assist where I can.

Comment: I left and arrow off and I added it and tested it on a subdirectory of my drive using text files and it works correctly.  However, again I recommend testing it thoroughly.  We are not here to provide free scripts and the nature of this script is such that it warrants thorough testing.

Comment: A lilbit change in project requirement. We could  have many folders and subfolders within those folders in google drive.in these folders we have different files e.g-docs,spreadsheets etc.WE have to check if similar name folders and subfolders are present in drive.If present, we have to move files from one folder to the other folder(having same name).Then we have to delete those folders from where files are merged in other folders having same name.Then we have to check for duplicate files(as it was merged, so duplicate files could be found) within the folders and subfolders.

Comment: Then We have to keep the last updated files and trash the other(duplicate file) from the folders and subfolders. Thanks cooper. I need your help regarding that. I am editing the post and sharing the code .please suggest change and edit it.

Comment: You would probably be better off to begin a new question.  Because I'm not interested in taking this any further.  This is not a free script writing service.